# Combine arrays into multidimensional array where key value is identical

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I've been literally searching and searching this site and the web for many hours, but I just dont seem to find the right answer.
What I'm trying to accomplish is getting a table from a database, combine the rows with the same value from a given column into a multidimensional array.

My table looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ww2uv.png

What I want is to make a multidimensional array where the setting_group_id is the same.
So I can use those build arrays to display setting sections on my administration panel.
Like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKHiY.png

The code I have this far is:

```
$query  = "SELECT * FROM bmp_settings";
$mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database);

// Check connection
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

if ($result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query)) {

        while($bmp_setting_groups = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r ($bmp_setting_groups);
            echo "</pre>";
        }
}

/* free the results */
mysqli_free_result($result);

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
```

What I get are 12 associative arrays.

Who can help me here?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM bmp_settings GROUP BY setting_group_id ORDER BY setting_group_id` Is that what you want...?

Comment: That's indeed what I want, but that merges all rows into one and I wasn't able to extract the singular settings from it. It gives me this back: http://i.imgur.com/8YN5aah.png

Comment: Ah! You want to invert the table?

Comment: I would want to do anything to group the rows with the same setting_group_id and build a "panel" for each group of settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this for complete code: http://hastebin.com/rakeceqefi.xml

---

So, you want something like this?

```
array(1) {
  'TeamSpeak' =>
  array(2) {
    'teamspeak_filetransfer_port' =>
    array(6) {
      'setting_label' =>
      string(17) "Filetransfer Port"
      'setting_helpblock' =>
      NULL
      'setting_type' =>
      string(4) "text"
      'setting_value' =>
      int(30033)
      'setting_options' =>
      NULL
      'setting_weight' =>
      int(4)
    }
    'teamspeak_port' =>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can do it like this:

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test_a', 'test', 'test'); //replace this with your credentials

$q1 = $conn->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT `setting_group_id` FROM `bmp_settings`');
$q1->execute();
$groups = array_fill_keys($q1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0), array());

$q2 = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `bmp_settings`");
$q2->execute();
$result = $q2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($result as $r) {
    $gName = $r['setting_group_id'];
    $sKey = $r['setting_key'];
    $groups[$gName][$sKey] = $r;
    unset($groups[$gName][$sKey]['setting_group_id']); // not really needed
    unset($groups[$gName][$sKey]['setting_key']); // not really needed
}
```

this gets you the array above.

Comment: That indeed looks like what I want! Because then I would be able to do something per arrray and use the variables given by the settings group.

Comment: Wow, that looks awesome! But now you lost me :P How should I use the groups? I just started recently started scripting in PHP and while I already now a lot, this is something I still have to learn about.

Comment: @Fonta What do you mean by "How should I use the groups"?

Comment: difficult to explain, might become clear when looking at the comments: http://hastebin.com/nalayitiqo.php

Comment: You mean how to build the actual panel?

Comment: Indeed, well at least how to use the variables gotten from the table. The result per settings group would become: http://i.imgur.com/VxMsWHk.png depending on where the settings are for and which settings there are.

Comment: Forget that, I got it! You sir, are awesome! http://i.imgur.com/fCw68nl.png with php: http://hastebin.com/zereboguje.php

Comment: No prob mate. I can post you some optimized code if you want

Comment: If you would like, please! That would be great! Btw, already came across the following challenge, Sorting the individual settings according to their weight.

Comment: @Fonta to sort by weight use the query `SELECT * FROM  \`bmp_settings\` ORDER BY \`setting_group_id\`, \`setting_weight\``